# Combine tables in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, pander

I am trying to combine two tables in R Markdown into a single table, one below the other & retaining the header. The figure below shows the desired output. After putting my markdown code I will show the actual output. I realize that the way I have structured the pander statements will not allow me to get the output I want but searching SO I was unsuccessful in finding the right way to do so.

I can do some post processing in Word to get the output exactly as I want but I am trying to avoid that overhead.

The **testdat.RData** file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hTmthiX5dpWDd5UTdlbWhocVE/view?usp=sharing

The **R Markdown RMD** file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0hTmthiX5dpSEFIcGRNQ1MzM1E/view?usp=sharing

**Desired Output**

[image: Desired Output]

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(pander)
load("testdat.RData")
pander::pander(t1,big.mark=',', justify=c('left','right','right','right'))
pander::pander(t2,big.mark=',', justify=c('left','right','right','right'))
```
````

**Actual Output**

[image: Actual Output]

Thanks,

Krishnan

Comment: you need to physically combine them and add collumn names as additional rows

Comment: Manually doing this in markdown wouldn't be overly difficult, but obviously you don't want to (and shouldn't have to) do it manually. You might be able to do something like `pander(rbind(t1,names(t2),t2))`

Comment: Carl - This workaround helps. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt using the `xtable` package:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, results="asis"}
library(xtable)

# Add thousands separator
t1[-1] = sapply(t1[-1], formatC, big.mark=",")
t2[-1] = sapply(t2[-1], formatC, big.mark=",")

t1$Mode = as.character(t1$Mode)

# Bind together t1, extra row of column names, and t2
t1t2 = rbind(t1, names(t1), t2)

# Render the table using xtable
print(xtable(t1t2, align="rrrrr"), # Right-align all columns (includes extra value for row names)
      include.rownames=FALSE, # Don't print rownames
      hline.after=NULL, 
      # Add midrules before/after each set column names
      add.to.row = list(pos = list(-1,0,4,5),
                        command = rep("\\midrule \n",4)))
```
````

And here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code. I ran it and here is the msg I get instead of the table. I think there might be pandoc/latex versioning issue. What version of latex (or Midtex - I am on a Windows 7 machine) are you using? 

*% latex table generated in R 3.1.3 by xtable 1.8-0 package %*

Also, when i ran it on my real dataset I get this error:


*Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Item 2 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> rbind -> rbind -> <Anonymous> -> rbindlist
Execution halted*

Comment: I'm on a Mac running Yosemite. MacTEX 2015, R 3.2.2, xtable 1.7-4.

Comment: It was useful in my case but I would lose the `linestretch` specified in the YAML header, which instead was respected by `kable()`

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to make a formal answer since my comment seemed to work for you.

```
pander(rbind(t1,names(t2),t2))
```

Comment: What is the types of the first columns are different while the rest of the columns are the same type?